# Can conditional screen flows be represented using storyboards?

Tags: ios

My UI will consist of a tab bar controller as the root controller with tabs for differing filters applied to a data set.

If there is some data in a particular set corresponding to a tab then a table view will be displayed, however then if there isn't any data then rather than displaying an empty table a different screen (with an image and some text and maybe a button) is displayed.

I was wondering how this relationship, specifically the conditional state (if data display table view, if no data display other view) can be represented using a storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. For this you should use the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method and notify your child view using `segue.destinationViewController`.